# Need help on jquery confirmation box

Tags: jquery

I need a customized Confirmation box in jquery which looks similar to the javascript confirmation box.
I need to customize the font(red color) in the confirmation box ?
Please help me and do the needful ...!

Comment: use jquery UI-dialog as confirm box..

Comment: u can provide the font color red in its style for fonts

Comment: I gone through the jquery UI dialog, how to edit the style sheet for the confirmation box ?
the jquery UI Confirmation box is loading on window load, how to open on the click event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uCfJ3/1/embedded/result/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
.html('You are going to open Facebook.com.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Confirm..?',
    buttons: {"OK": function() { 
                  $(this).dialog("close"); 
                  window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
                  return true;
             }, "Cancel": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  return false;
             }
    }
});  

 $('#myOpener').click(function(e){
    return $myDialog.dialog('open');  
 });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCfJ3/1/)

Comment: Thank you.it works perfect.
I need it on button click ?
How to add the css?

Comment: Give button id in place of `myOpener` in `$('#myOpener').click()`...   Also you can see the css on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCfJ3/1/) link at the bottom of my answer..

Comment: its working good in fiddle and i am trying the same code in asp.net, the css is not applying proper and the confirmation window is opening and closing in 1 sec.. !
please let me know what script and css need to add to the page ?

Comment: In the fiddle, as you can see I have used jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2..  You may also need to include jQuery ui css from [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: i have added the cdn to my page
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

and in the fiddle you have override the widget layout and content, where i have to place and i need to mention in other css file ?

Comment: Just put the overriding css in the head but only after calling the jQuery UI css ...